# CvVideoCamera - camera not available, Iphone simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, opencv

Following example of initialization and start of CvVideoCamera in swift project for IOS. Xcode 7.3.1, Using pre-built opencv 2.4.13 Executing on simulator IOS 9.3.
I have tried two version of CvVideoCamera initialization and start. One , directly in swift view controller, another in objective C wrapper with the same effect.
For easier debugging I call my initCamera followed by startCamera from IBaction triggered by button, rather than from viewDidLoad.
I was expecting that after that sequence the simulator would turn the macbook camera on and direct the video to the simulator.

The camera does not start ( the LED indicator is off and I am not receiving video in parent UIImageView).
There is one message in the application console:
2016-06-10 21:13:20.777 ocvtest2[57252:2485915] camera available: N

Is my macbook camera supposed to be available for the simulator by default or it requires some additional setup?
How to trouble shoot the issue?
Thank you

my initCamera and startCamera methods :

```
var myCamera : CvVideoCamera!
var videoCameraWrapper : CvVideoCameraWrapper!
var cameraInitialized : Bool = false
var cameraStarted : Bool = false

func startCamera()
{
  if(cameraInitialized == true && cameraStarted == false)
  {
    myCamera.start();
    cameraStarted = true
  }
}

func initCamera(parentView: UIImageView!)
{
    if cameraInitialized
    { return }

    myCamera = CvVideoCamera(parentView: imageView)
    myCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front;
    myCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
    myCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
    myCamera.defaultFPS = 30
    myCamera.grayscaleMode = false
    myCamera.delegate = self

    cameraInitialized = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the camera is not available to the simulator.

This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html) contains information on what the simulator can and cannot do.